# DAX Formula to Count all Distinct Customers in a specific region

Tags: powerbi, dax, data-modeling, datamodel

I want to calculate all distinct customers in a specific region. But the problem here is that my table "Customer" does not have a direct relationship with territory table, instead it has an indirect relationship.

ER Diagram of my data model is :

[image]

Comment: If you have proper relation "Territory>>Sales>>Customer" you should not face any issue for your purpose. Can you show the Measure code you are trying with?

Comment: I do have proper relation between all of these defined tables, I just want to know what will be its DAX formula to calculate this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a measure with **RELATED** function as below. For direction in table relation, I have used table **Sales** and **Region** which will also give you correct answer-

```
customer_for_region_2 = 

CALCULATE(
    DISTINCTCOUNT(Sales[cus-id]),
    FILTER(
        Sales,
        RELATED(Region[regionid]) = 2 //Hard coded region id
    )
)
```